# Finding the index of rows based on a sequence of values in a column of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column that has three unique character strings. What I need to do is to generate a list containing indexes of rows that has 'very bad' after good, but not 'very bad' after 'bad'.

```py
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'measure': [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(0,20)],
})

df['status'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 'good' if x['measure'] > 4 else 'very bad' if x['measure'] < 2  else 'bad',
    axis=1)
```

```
    measure    status
0         8      good
1         8      good
2         0  very bad
3         5      good
4         2       bad
5         3       bad
6         9      good
7         9      good
8        10      good
9         5      good
10        1  very bad
11        7      good
12        7      good
13        6      good
14        5      good
15       10      good
16        3       bad
17        0  very bad
18        3       bad
19        5      good
```

I expect to get this list:

[2, 10]

Is there a one line solution to this?

I don't want to use numeric values as they are used purely here to generate the DataFrame or loop over all rows which is computationally expensive for my use case.

Comment: Can you clean/edited your question I see no 'very good' in your data.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks for spotting that, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe index is default range index, then you can use this:

```
np.where((df['status'] == 'very bad') & (df['status'].shift() == 'good'))[0]
```

Output:

```
array([ 2, 10], dtype=int64)
```

Else, you can use the following:

```
irow = np.where((df['status'] == 'very bad') & (df['status'].shift() == 'good'))[0]
df.index[irow]
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott, I have a slightly different version of this question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736020/generating-a-tuple-of-indexes-based-on-a-sequence-of-values-in-a-pandas-datafram Do you mind helping me on that too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `eq`, `shift`, and `loc`

```
s = df.status.eq('very bad')
s1 = df.status.eq('good').shift()

In [30]: (s & s1).loc[lambda x:x].index.tolist()
Out[30]: [2, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[lambda x:x.status.eq('very bad') & x.status.shift().eq('good')].index.tolist()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26095128)