# Generating a tuple of indexes based on a sequence of values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It's a follow up to my previous question here: [Finding the index of rows based on a sequence of values in a column of pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61735585/finding-the-index-of-rows-based-on-a-sequence-of-values-in-a-column-of-pandas-da)

I want to get a list of tuples that has index of very bad, followed with the the index of first occurrence of 'bad':

```py
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'measure': [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(0,20)],
})

df['status'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 'good' if x['measure'] > 4 else 'very bad' if x['measure'] < 2  else 'bad',
    axis=1)
```

Here's the data frame:

```
    measure    status
0         8      good
1         8      good
2         0  very bad
3         5      good
4         2       bad
5         3       bad
6         9      good
7         9      good
8        10      good
9         5      good
10        1  very bad
11        7      good
12        7      good
13        6      good
14        5      good
15       10      good
16        3       bad
17        0  very bad
18        3       bad
```

How can I get a tuple of such combinations?

[(2,4), (10,16), (17,18)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
# filters only rows with bad and very bad
m = df[df['status'].isin(['bad','very bad'])] 

# check id current row is very bad and next row is bad
c = m['status'].eq('very bad') & m['status'].shift(-1).eq('bad')

# if true return next row as true too and get only index values
idx = m[c|c.shift()].index

# convert every 2 items into a tuple
res = [*zip(idx[::2],idx[1::2])]
```

---

```
[(2, 4), (10, 16), (17, 18)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add some comment on how you get here?

Comment: @MehdiZare Edited with comments

Comment: Your comments are speaking words but I don't have the intellect to translate to code.  +1

Comment: @r.ook i dont think so friend. I have seen you answering and I can vouch for your intellect :-) bdw let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @anky Would be great if you can explain how line 3 get the indexes correctly! `idx = m[c|c.shift()].index`

Comment: @MehdiZare c returns true only if current row is very bad and next row is bad. Hence we return both the current row as true and next row as true for boolan indexing

Comment: So how does it work when there are some rows between very bad and bad?

Comment: @MehdiZare Because in variable m we already filtered out other rows which are not very bad or bad